# Error trying to implement amp-mustache

Tags: json, jekyll, mustache, amp-html, amp-mustache

I am trying to replicate [this example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/) with no success. I want to add a list using a `mustache` template, like this:

```
<ul>
    <amp-list width=auto
              height=100
              layout=fixed-height
              src="/assets/popular.json">
          <template type="amp-mustache"
                    id="amp-template-id">
              <li>
                  <a href={{url}}>{{title}}</a>
              </li>
          </template>
    </amp-list>
</ul>
```

My `/assets/popular.json` file is:

```
{
 "items": [
   {
     "title": "amp-carousel",
     "url": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel"
   },
   {
     "title": "amp-img",
     "url": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img"
   },
   {
     "title": "amp-ad",
     "url": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-ad"
   },
   {
     "title": "amp-accordion",
     "url": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-accordion"
   }
 ]
}
```

But I cannot get it to work, the values in the `json` are not being replaced in the template, I get this error:

```
Missing URL for attribute 'href' in tag 'a'
```

I do not know why the value `{{url}}` is not being replaced properly with the content of the `json`.

I've added the necessary `scripts` in the head.

Comment: I think your json file is not loaded correctly, please check in the network tab to see if you are getting the file.

Comment: @ShlomiHaver, Yes, I am getting the file.

Comment: Can you put our code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver You can check it live here: https://elbauldelprogramador.com/tags/ 

The amp-list shoud appear at the beggining (Currently there is a blank space due to the error)

Comment: I would like to see the error you are getting in a fiddle so i could try and help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently I've been migrating to **Hugo** from **Jekyll** and have faced the same issue. Below are solutions for both.

## Jekyll

It is solved now, the problem was I am using `jekyll`, and so the tags `{{tag}}`  were being interpreted as a `liquid tag`. I solved it writing the code like this:

```
<ul>
<amp-list width=auto
    height=100
    layout=fixed-height
    src="/assets/popular.json">
  <template type="amp-mustache"
      id="amp-template-id">
    <li>
      <a href="{% raw %}{{url}}{% endraw %}">{% raw %}{{title}}{% endraw %}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
</amp-list>
</ul>
```

**Update**: I have written a [more detailed explanation](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/how-to-solve-missing-url-for-attribute-src-in-tag-a-error-in-amp-mustache/)

## Hugo

```
<ul>
<amp-list width=auto
    height=100
    layout=fixed-height
    src="/assets/popular.json">
  <template type="amp-mustache"
      id="amp-template-id">
    <li>
      <a class="card related" id={{"{{id}}"}} {{ printf "href=%q" "{{url}}" | safeHTMLAttr }}>
         {{"{{title}}"}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </template>
</amp-list>
</ul>
```